# How can i check and return if there is value in a list with values in JSON format in java

Tags: java, list, contains

I want to see if in my List is live67 parameter, I have seen other posts on how to see if there is a value in the List, however my list has values in JSON format and it is not working for me. After that I want to return 3da2f0db339742f257ecbe737855cd6e -> value for test67.

I try:

```
streamService.getAllStreams().contains("test67")
```

My List:

```
[
    {
        "key": "3da2f0db339742f257ecbe737855cd6e",
        "streamName": "test67"
    },
    {
        "key": "35ad38ffb46c2ba97306ca931e003481",
        "streamName": "test68"
    }
]
```

in streamDao class:

```
public List<Stream> selectAllStreams();
```

in StreamService:

```
public List<Stream> getAllStreams(){
        return streamDao.selectAllStreams();
    }
```

in StreamController:

```
@GetMapping("/getList")
public List<Stream> getAllStreams(){
    if(streamService.getAllStreams().contains("test67")){
    return streamService.getAllStreams();
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

always get null

This is my Stream class:

```
public class Stream {

    String key;
    String streamName;

    public Stream(String streamName, String key){

        this.streamName = streamName;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getStreamName() {
        return streamName;
    }

}
```

Comment: A List of `Stream` will never contain any `String` at all.  You'll need to test if your list contains a stream that has the streamname `"test67"` not wether your list directly contains the String `"test67"` as that is impossible.

Comment: You should declare `Stream.toString()`. Maybe `List.contains()`  will use `Object.toString()` to search an object.

Comment: where I should declare it?

Comment: I added answer below, but I didn't test it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the java stream api

```java
public List<Stream> getAllStreams(){
    var optionalStream = streamService.getAllStreams().stream()
       .filter(str -> str.getStreamName().equals("test67")).findFirst();

    if (optionalStream.isPresent()) {
         return streamDao.selectAllStreams();
         // return optionalStream.get().getKey(); To return the Key value of stream test67
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @Saurabh Jhunjhunwala, you made my code incorrect

Comment: Thanks!! I would also like to ask how to return the key value for streamName "test67" which is 3da2f0db339742f257ecbe737855cd6e?

Comment: Something like, when it finds the value "test67" returns the key value for it, instead of streamDao.selectAllStreams();

Comment: To get the key value use `return optionalStream.get().getKey()`. However please inform yourself about java streams and optionals, so you actually learn how to use them ;)

Comment: Yes, I know I'm just reading about it to understand what you wrote, thank you once again :)

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way to figure out this problem, please override `toString()` method.

```java
public class Stream {

    String key;
    String streamName;

    public Stream(String streamName, String key){

        this.streamName = streamName;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getStreamName() {
        return streamName;
    }

/// override toString()
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getStreamName();
    }

}
```

In fact, `Object.toString()` is used for *authenticate* an object in all other external library classes.
Because of this, returning unique value of `toString()` with all properties of object in it - this is a regular way.

But in your case, this is the fastest way.

Or you need to implement method alternantive of `List.contains()`.